# Does the sarorderedprobit function in the sarprobit package support panel or timeseries datasets (within r)?

Tags: r, spatial

I am attempting to use the sarorderedprobit function (within the "spatialprobit" package) to perform a SAR Ordered Probit estimation using panel data.

I have imported my spatial weight matrix (representing the 50 states of the US) using the following script:

```
Weight_GAL<- read.gal(File, override.id=TRUE)
Weight_List<nb2listw(Weight_GAL,style="W", zero.policy=TRUE)
W<-listw2mat(Weight_List)
```

which successfully imports the 50x50 sparse matrix.

The following sarorderedprobit is run:

```
sarorderedprobit(formula, W=W, showProgress=TRUE)
```

When using cross-sectional data with 50 observations, the script successfully estimates the sarorderedprobit model. However, when panel data is used with 3 years (i.e., 150 observations), the script returns the following error:

> Error: Matrices must have same dimensions in .Arith.Csparse(e1,e2, .Generic, class. = dgCMatrix")

The issue here seems to be related to the use of a 50x50 weight matrix with 150 observations. Unfortunately, I have not found any references to using the sarorderedprobit function with panel data. Can anyone provide guidance on whether the sarorderedprobit function supports estimation using panel or timeseries datasets?

EDIT:

I have calculated the Kronecker product using a sparse matrix to prepare a 150x150 weight matrix using the following script:

```
tperiods <- len(3)
t_diag <- Diagonal(tperiods)
bigWmat <- kronecker(t_diag,W)
```

Running the sarorderedprobit function using the bigWmat matrix is successful with no errors. However, I am concerned that this is not correctly handling the temporal nature of the panel data estimation. Do I need to add response dummy variables with the time periods (t=1, t=2, t=3 for the 3 years of panel data)?

Comment: I don't have all the pieces to this puzzle. However, check to make sure that when using the panel data, that both weights and the data have the same number of observations. If they don't it causes this error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kat. The issue is that using a 150x150 matrix is not treating the data set as panel data. For example, when running a SDM model in STATA using panel data, xsmle command (model SDM) uses panel estimation with the 50x50 matrix.

Comment: Over a year later... but I do not think that the sarorderedprobit() function handles panel data. The help file of the function says, for example, that `y`, the dependent variable, is an `(n x 1)` vector of discrete choices. In a panel context, it would have been an `(nT x 1)` vector where `n` is the number of spatial units and `T` the number of time periods. I am tempted to run one regression for each time period in my panel (T = 72), just to see how my coefficients estimates (especially `rho`) change over time.